# parallel_for - Which loop to parallelize?

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing

I have 3-times nested loop, whereas the two outer loops loop only very few times as opposed to the most inner loop. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {

                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

I ~= J << K, i.e I roughly equals J, but K is very much larger (a factor of few thousands)

Since all of the data are independent of each other, I would like to parallelize them using parallel_for of the ppl.h library. The question now arises, which loop do I parallelize? I'm tending towards the innermost loop, since its the largest, but I assume that every time the outer loops loop, the whole threading overheads starts again. So what is more efficient?

Comment: Try all 3 ways, benchmark (across a variety of data), then pick apart any surprising results. "Why is.." questions are usually more interesting than "Which is.." questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question now arises, which loop do I parallelize?

Typically, you'd want to parallelize the outermost loop that makes sense.  If you parallelize the inner loops, you are introducing extra overhead.  By having the "loop bodies" be as large as possible, you'll get better overall throughput.  This really boils down to [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) - in this case, the overhead involved in scheduling the parallel work items is not parallelizable, so the more of that work you do, the lower the potential efficiency overall.

The risk is that, if there are too few items in the outer loop, you may end up where work items can't be run in parallel, since there will be a point where there are fewer items than processing cores in your system.

Provided that your outer loop has enough to keep the cores busy, it's the best place to go - especially if the amount of work done in each loop body is relatively consistent.

Comment: Write conflicts, which aren't shown in the question, would be the other major factor I'd consider.

Comment: @BenVoigt True - though in general, those are only made worse by parallelizing at a lower level.

Comment: Your correct. I just tested out each loop, and parallelizing the outer most loop was the fastest, even though it iterates until 4, whereas the innermost iterates until around 20k.